# WindowsDriver.common.targets error

Tags: visual-studio-2013, device-driver, wdk

I have installed Visual Studio 2013 then installed Windows Driver Kit (WDK) 8.1. I'm using Windows 7. I already had a project which is a modified fastfat. I was building that using VS 2012 and everything was fine. But today when I try to build the same project using VS2013 I get the following error:

C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\build\WindowsDriver.common.targets(77,5): error : Unknown or unsupported property value (Vista) for TargetVersion

Note that I ran the clean procedure before doing the build.

Does anyone know what to try next?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What flavor of Visual Studio 2013 are you using (i.e., Professional, Premium or Ultimate)?

Be aware that Professional does not support Device Driver Templates. Check this by clicking on File/New/Project. Then Templates/Visual C++. If "Windows Driver" does not show up then your flavor does not support device drivers. I would try Ultimate.

Comment: That makes sense. My 2012 was Ultimate but my 2013 was Professional. I'll try Ultimate and let you know what happens.

Comment: I loaded Ultimate and that fixed the problem. Thanks.